# Surjective and injective properties of two sets

Tags: analysis

If I have some set $A$ and a subset $B$, where the cardinality of $A$ is greater than $B$, can I have either a bijection, surjection, or injection?

In other words, lets say I have some sequence where every element is in the set of Natural numbers, and $f(x+1) > f(x)$. Then I have some subset of the natural numbers $B$ such that it coins only the even elements of the natural numbers. Can this be a bijection or surjection?

Comment: You can only have a surjection from $A$ to $B$ if that's what you are asking.

Comment: What i'm asking is that since A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.......} and B = {2,4,6,8,10,.....}, we know every element in B is in A. But we know A has the odd numbers left over that cannot be found in B. But we know A goes on infinitely and so does B, and since B contains every element that is in A isn't this a bijection? Or if we have the mapping of the natural numbers to f(x) = 2x where x is in the natural numbers, this sequence would be a mapping of the natural numbers to a set that only contains the evens. Every element in the natural numbers will be mapped but not every natural number is in B.

Comment: The cardinality of A and B in this comment are the same.  What does this have to do with your question?

Comment: So I am doing a proof in analysis and I am given a sequence An and some other sequence Af(n), this means that every element of Af(n) is in An, wouldn't this also be a bijection? We know f(n+1) > f(n) and that An is absolutely convergent.

Comment: If there is a bijetion between two sets they must have the same cardinality.  Since $f(n) = 2n$ is a bijection from the natural numbers to the even numbers, The cardinality of the even numbers equals the cardinality of the natural numbers.  Counter-intuitive, isn't it.

Comment: Yes very haha thats what is getting me confused. So if the even number set was finite would it NOT be a bijection?